# retrieve user's hometown from facebook in android application

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to learn the way integrating facebook in your application it works.

So, until now I found out how to retrieve user's name or gender but I'm not able to found out his hometown.

Here is how I did it:

```
 mRequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestButton);

 mRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAsyncRunner.request("me", new SampleRequestListener());
            }
        });



 public class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
             ..........


    JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
    final String name = json.getString("name");
    final String locale=json.getString("locale");
            ..........
           }
```

Now I was able to find both `name` and `locale` but when I do try to find the hometown doing like:

```
  final String hometown=json.getString("hometown");
```

This string is empty....does anyone know how is the proper way to find the hometown???In here :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ it says that for finding out the hometown I need permissions....how I get those permissions???Can anyone tell me and posts o few lines of code?Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hometown is another JSONObject which contains 2 strings, ID and name, so you want to extract the JSONObject called "hometown" then use `json.getString("name");` to extract the name of the hometown.

Example:

```
public class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
         ..........

JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
final String name = json.getString("name");
final String locale=json.getString("locale");

JSONObject hometown = json.getJSONObject("hometown");
final String town = hometown.getString("name");


        ..........
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you output the JSON file and see what data is exposed?

Comment: And how do I output this file?

Comment: You have a JSON object - thats got everything in it... output that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this when creating your facebook object? I think by permission they mean the fields in the permissions column on that docs page needs to go inside here:

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "user_hometown" },
```